# Page_ClientValidate is not defined

Tags: asp.net, client-side

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and I'm using IE8 as my default browser but no matter how many times I try, **Page_ClientValidate** keeps giving me this error that it is not defined. How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Can you post details of error?

Comment: Happens to me too, also in FireFox while using .NET 4.0. A couple of minutes ago it happened with the variable Page_IsValid, but now it happens with Page_ClientValidate as well...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

..so.. i think may be there is not any RequiredValidator Control in your page~~