# Whether to use Page_IsValid or Page_ClientValidate() (for Client Side Events)

Tags: asp.net

I have following code inside a button click handler. Both approaches work fine. The `Page_ClientValidate()` causes an extra validation check and do processing whereas `Page_IsValid` makes use of existing property.

QUESTIONS

1. In case of button click, is it always guaranteed that `Page_IsValid` would have been calculated by that time? If is not guaranteed, we need to call `Page_ClientValidate()` explicitly.
2. What are the events that happen before `Page_IsValid` is set? For such events we should not rely on `Page_IsValid`

**UPDATE**

Is it assured that the button click event handler (in JavaScript) will be called only after the validation part is completed (i.e., after Page_ClientValidate() was invoked as part of validation) ? If this is assured, can I rely on Page_IsValid?

**SCRIPT**

```
  $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {

  //Aproach 1
  var isValid = Page_ClientValidate('');
  if (isValid) 
  {
       //Do reamining work
  }

  //Aproach 2
  if (Page_IsValid)
  {
      //Do reamining work
  }

  });
```

**REFERENCES**:

1. [Hide redundant error message in ASP.Net ValidationSummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565718/hide-redundant-error-message-in-asp-net-validationsummary)
2. [Validator causes improper behavior for double click check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825543/validator-causes-improper-behavior-for-double-click-check?lq=1)
3. [Page_ClientValidate is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227830/page-clientvalidate-is-not-defined)
4. [Page_ClientValidate is validating multiple times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969465/problem-with-page-clientvalidate)
5. [MSDN - ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx)

Comment: This Page_IsValid never worked for me in javascript. I always use Page_ClientValidate in javascript and Page_IsValid in server side code

Comment: @Moons have you ever posted the issue in stack overflow - "Page_IsValid never worked for me in javascript" ?

Comment: Actually not. I tried once using Page_IsValid and it didnt worked and then i started using Page_ClientValidate

Comment: Page_IsValid sets in  ValidatorUpdateIsValid() which is inside Page_ClientValidate() and Page_ClientValidate() is inside WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(). Everytime when you do postback with standart control this event fires. Otherwise if you call for example __doPostBack() of course you have to call Page_ClientValidate() for validation.

Comment: Page_ClientValidate() invokes ValidatorUpdateIsValid(), this function invokes AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators) where  Page_Validators array of validator objects. AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators) checks isvalid property for every validator and return result (true or false) what assigns to the Page_IsValid  Example: function ValidatorUpdateIsValid() {
    Page_IsValid = AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators);

Answer (score 4):

1. In case of button click, `Page_ClientValidate()` is called when (and only when) the button's `CausesValidation` is set to `true`.
2. `Page_ClientValidate()` is part of process of doing postback, so it is called within button's click.
   I rely on `Page_IsValid` only in a scope of a function **after** calling `Page_ClientValidate()`. Otherwise I **always** call `Page_ClientValidate()`.

Comment: calling `Page_ClientValidate()` repeatedly may cause the page to be too obtrusive (multiple alerts etc.). That's why it's good to have a custom validate function that takes care of all validation.

Comment: Is it assured that the button click event handler (in JavaScript) will be called only after the validation part is completed (i.e., after Page_ClientValidate() was invoked as part of validation) ? If this is assured, I can rely on Page_IsValid.

Comment: @Lijo: See my first point - it is assured only when the button's `CausesValidation` is set to `true`.